# Calendar value not updating in android service

Tags: android, toast

In this android service I wanna display a toast of value of second at current time. but this again and again show the same value. timer is scheduled to update at interval of 1 second but the value don't refresh and toast shows the previous value again. I don't what the issue.

```
package net.learn2develop.Services;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service{

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Timer t = new Timer();
    int second = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int temp = 6;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        Toast.makeText(this,"service started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                second = timeSecond();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
//                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(second), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            }
        };
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 4* 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        t.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public int timeSecond() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.SECOND)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I guess the `Calendar` object doesn't update its time automatically, so you will need to create a new `Calendar` instance every time (in the `timeSecond` method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

returns a calendar whose time fields have been initialized with the current date and time. Those values do not then change as time passes. So when you use:

```
String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.SECOND))
```

you are getting the same values every time. You need a new instance of calendar in each iteration of your timer.